# Category for Receipt OCR

Tags: android, dictionary, tesseract

I am trying to create a receipt OCR app using tesseract. After the recognition process, I want to determine which category the receipt belongs to, e.g Food & Drinks, Transportation, Phone bills etc. My current approach is:

1. Create a dictionary of categories alongside some common stores.
2. After recognition, I will use approximate string matching to try and find the store name inside the dictionary and if it exists, I will allocate the receipt to that category.
3. If it is not found, I will allocate the receipt to a default category and wait for the user to select one from a list. I will then save this pair in the dictionary for the future.

The problem is that apart from the limitations of store to category pairs, it will be extremely slow if I try to use approximate string recognition for each line with the dictionary. Is there any way I can improve this process?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Store Categories and don't match up to useful spend categories (think - what did I buy at Target, or Staples?) or buying coffee at Staples vs the grocery store.

This API:
https://apidocs.itemize.com/enterprise/ 
Will do what you are trying to do.